# Calling AsyncTask from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I need your help I have been stuck on this for the past two days, I'm trying to call this AsyncTask from another activity and get the string that is returned but after reading several post on the net and on SO I'm unable to do it. Could someone point out what I need to do or very cheekily post some code and explain it so I know whats going on. I really appreciate the help!

E.g

```
String jsonString = //returned string from AsyncTask 



public class processJSON extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{

        private Context context;

        public processJSON (Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

            int location_id = (Integer) params[0];
            String url = (String) params[1];

            InputStream in = null;
            String result = "";
            JSONObject jArray = null;
            String newURL = url + "?location_id=" + location_id;

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); 
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try{

                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(newURL);
                //json.put("location_id", location_id);
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);

                if (response != null) {
                    in = response.getEntity().getContent(); 
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Send JSON", "ERROR: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                in.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `AsyncTask` should accept a callback as an argument when you instantiate it.  Then, once it has run and completed, you can return whatever values you've generated through the callback.

Comment: Thanks I'm currently looking at example on Google, will update once I'm done.

Comment: No need. Make class processJSON abstract, and then instantiate object of it in your activity and override onPostExecute, that's it.

Comment: @VladimirLichonos Ah, that's pretty good.  I'll have to remember that.